# Container name is not resolved in compose, but IP is

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-network

I run two containers in compose mode. Containers can communicate with each other by IP, but not by container name - it is not resolved.

Docker network inspect where containers are ran

---

```
docker inspect mycompose
[
    {
        "Name": "mycompose",
        "Id": "5d6f614b1a67efa38143adf745700cac103be07f74bcb219fd547aa8ce8abd1e",
        "Created": "2019-11-07T17:08:49.940162+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.144.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.144.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "876efda0f26487b4c56dd52485e6f76ecc5c97214ae99cb0760a5cad4c65ea74": {
                "Name": "mycompose_brim_1",
                "EndpointID": "15a3049b1f79d5da3129030574fd16dc46ced5246f15fe00b08b778a2b8ab8ef",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:57:23:87",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.144.113/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b8c596491ae84a1da8d597ea6ab6edf5872405856520e46d8f35581f48314b5f": {
                "Name": "mycompose_brimdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "8bbf233cfeb57729570f581dd34f6677a6a6655dd64c2090dacc26b91604eb7c",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:57:25:be",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.113.185/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "48240B53-F49A-43B9-9A20-113C047D65A1"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "v2",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "mycompose",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1"
        }
    }
]
```

---

Trying to ping one container within another by container name:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> ping mycompose_brimdb_1
Ping request could not find host mycompose_brimdb_1. Please check the name and try again
```

Trying to ping by service name:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> ping brimdb
Ping request could not find host brimdb. Please check the name and try again.
```

Trying to ping same container by IP:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> ping 172.25.113.185

Pinging 172.25.113.185 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.25.113.185: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.25.113.185: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.25.113.185: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.25.113.185: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.25.113.185:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 1ms
```

---

compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  brim:
    image: brim:latest
    ports:
      - target: 50893
        published: 50893
        protocol: tcp

  brimdb:
    image: brimdb:latest
    ports:
      - target: 1555
        published: 1555
        protocol: tcp
```

Comment: use service name that you set in the compose when you defined it.

Comment: good suggestion, but I have tried it as well, nothing... my bad though, adding to the dscription

Comment: also I just realized - another container is resolved even by container ID, but not by name or service...